# dnsserverresourcerecord - all expanded properties and zone

Tags: powershell, dns, customproperty

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName server -ZoneName zone.com
```

I want to run this command and get the HostName, RecordType, ZoneName and All RecordData sets.

I have something like so far:

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord zone.com -ComputerName server |
    select hostname, recordType, name,
        @{Name='ARecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}},
        @{Name='CNameRecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.HostnameAlias}}
```

My issue is two fold.

1. I need to know how to get the ZoneName into the record set so if I wanted to pass multiple zones I can keep that data separate.
2. The above example will create different columns for each RecordData.  As a DNS record will only have one of these values is there a way to combine them into one column through PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add the zone name as a [calculated property](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) just like you do with the record data.

   ```
   foreach ($zone in $zone_list) {
       Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone -ComputerName server |
           Select-Object hostname, @{n='ZoneName';e={$zone}}, recordType, ...
   }
   ```
2. Don't create individual properties, instead use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-3.0) statement to select the relevant data depending on the record type in a single property.

   ```
   ... | Select-Object hostname ..., @{n='Data';e={
       $rr = $_
       switch ($rr.RecordType) {
           'A'     {$rr.RecordData.IPv4Address}
           'CNAME' {$rr.RecordData.HostnameAlias}
           ...
       }
   }}
   ```

Comment: So first item 1 works great and thank you for that as something soo simple has been plaguing me for a long time.  Part 2 though I can't get to work as the Data column comes back empty.  I'm looking into this but just a heads up from first test.

Comment: Code:@{n='Data';e={
    switch ($_.RecordType) {
        'A'     {$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}
        'CNAME' {$_.RecordData.HostnameAlias}
        'NS' {$_.RecordData.NameServer}
        'SOA' {$_.RecordData.PrimaryServer}
        'SRV' {$_.RecordData.DomainName}
        'PTR' {$_.RecordData.PtrDomainName}
        'MX' {$_.RecordData.MailExchange}
        'AAAA' {$_.RecordData.IPv6Address}
        'TXT' {$_.RecordData.DescriptiveText}
        }
}}

Comment: @JamieLawson My bad. `$_` in the action blocks refers to the matched item (here `$_.RecordType`), which doesn't have the properties you want to expand. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you this was the fix.  Any information in understanding the change? Really confused by the fact what I see is you set $rr = $_ which is what we were using already and then went and replaced all the $_ with $rr.  If there is something I could read on this or something.  Otherwise a big thank you for all the help.

Comment: @JamieLawson The current object variable `$_` may have different values depending on the context in which it's used. In `switch ($_.RecordType) { 'A' { $_.RecordData } ... }` the first `$_` and the second `$_` refer to different objects (first one is the object received from the pipeline, second one is the value used in the switch comparison, i.e. the value of the property `RecordType`). Assigning `$_` to a regular variable (`$rr`) *before* the `switch` statement ensures that you're referencing the same object in the test value *and* the action blocks.